# Mega Menu with Alpinejs - Hover is Buggy

Tags: javascript, css, menu, megamenu, alpine.js

I'm trying to create a Mega Menu that triggers on Hover, using Tailwind CSS and Alpinejs. I kind of having it working, but it's really buggy.

I've tried adding x-on:mouseleave to different elements but it will either flicker constantly or only disappear when moving away from certain areas. So it will either disappear when moving below the menu and not when moving above and vice versa.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

https://codepen.io/kennyk3/pen/yLJmzYJ

```
<div class="bg-blue-800 hidden md:block">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto">
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap">
      <div class="w-full block flex-grow md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto">
        <div class="font-bold md:flex-grow">
          <ul class="flex justify-between">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li class="group hover:bg-white">
              <div x-data="{ resourcesMenu: false }" x-on:mouseover="resourcesMenu = !resourcesMenu" x-on:mouseleave="resourcesMenu = !resourcesMenu">
                <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-orange-400 group-hover:text-blue-900 transition duration-500">MEGA MENU</a>

                <div x-show="resourcesMenu" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-200" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 -translate-y-1" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 -translate-y-1" class="absolute inset-x-0 transform shadow-lg -mt-1 z-10">
                  <div class="bg-white">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto grid gap-y-6 px-4 py-6 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-8 sm:px-6 sm:py-8 lg:grid-cols-4 lg:px-8 lg:py-12 xl:py-16">

                      <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        <div class="flex md:h-full lg:flex-col">
                          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                              <svg class="h-6 w-6" x-description="Heroicon name: chart-bar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 19v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2zm0 0V9a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v10m-6 0a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2m0 0V5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2z"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ml-4 md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-between lg:ml-0 lg:mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                Analytics
                              </p>
                              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                Get a better understanding of where your traffic is coming from.
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600 lg:mt-4">Learn more <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>

                      <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        <div class="flex md:h-full lg:flex-col">
                          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                              <svg class="h-6 w-6" x-description="Heroicon name: cursor-click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ml-4 md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-between lg:ml-0 lg:mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                Engagement
                              </p>
                              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                Speak directly to your customers in a more meaningful way.
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600 lg:mt-4">Learn more <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>

                      <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        <div class="flex md:h-full lg:flex-col">
                          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                              <svg class="h-6 w-6" x-description="Heroicon name: shield-check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ml-4 md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-between lg:ml-0 lg:mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                Security
                              </p>
                              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                Your customers' data will be safe and secure.
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600 lg:mt-4">Learn more <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>

                      <a href="#" class="-m-3 p-3 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        <div class="flex md:h-full lg:flex-col">
                          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                              <svg class="h-6 w-6" x-description="Heroicon name: view-grid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM14 6a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2V6zM4 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2zM14 16a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v2a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2v-2z"></path>
                              </svg>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ml-4 md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-between lg:ml-0 lg:mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                Integrations
                              </p>
                              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                                Connect with third-party tools that you're already using.
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600 lg:mt-4">Learn more <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li class="md:hidden lg:inline-block">
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li class="md:hidden">
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>

            <li class="md:hidden lg:inline-block">
              <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-blue-100 hover:bg-blue-900 transition duration-500">LINK</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your trigger event from `mouseover` to `mouseenter`. The problem you're having is `mouseover` is triggered for the parent and its child elements.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

> The mouseover event is fired at an Element when a pointing device (such as a mouse or trackpad) is used to move the cursor onto the element or one of its child elements.

Wheres `mouseenter` will be triggered once.

Comment: Thanks. `mouseenter` is good choice because it will keep its enter position while hovering in to the dropdown content. Where as `mouseover` will not work on child / dropdown content. Thanks again.